# How to combine Lucene SpanQueries to match content between some delimiter Tokens?

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, match

Maybe it's an easy question but I can't find any idea how to handle this situation.

I want to search for documents in a Lucene index, where my documents have a stored field called `content` and its text is tokenized in this way:

```
DELIMITER_TOKEN
TOKEN_1                |
TOKEN_2                |  <- this is the first "block"
...                    |     (bounded by some delimiter tokens)
TOKEN_N                |
DELIMITER_TOKEN
TOKEN_1                |
TOKEN_2                |  <- another block...
...                    |
DELIMITER_TOKEN
...                    |  <- and so on...
```

I want to search for documents which contains for example `TOKEN_1`, `TOKEN_3`, and `TOKEN_8`, but in between the same `DELIMITER_TOKEN` pair.

My first idea was that I could create a `SpanNearQuery` for the searched terms with a large slop, then I could create a `SpanNotQuery` which I could use to exclude the overlapping DELIMITER_TOKENs from the previous query's matches, so I wouldn't get matches like

```
DELIMITER_TOKEN
TOKEN_1
TOKEN_3
DELIMITER_TOKEN
TOKEN_8
```

I guess this solution should work.

But sometimes I have to handle more complex cases, such as searching for

```
TOKEN_1 TOKEN_2 TOKEN_8 DELIMITER_TOKEN TOKEN_3 DELIMITER_TOKEN
```

...which means that I want to find a "block" in a document which contains (among others) the TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2 and TOKEN_8 tokens, and it has a block next to it, which contains TOKEN_3 (among others).

My idea is to use SpanNotQueries like in the simple case, and create a SpanNearQuery like this:

```
new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
        queryForFirstBlock,
        queryForDelimiter,
        queryForSecondBlock}
        0,
        true);
```

But I think this wouldn't work because the query for the first block don't necessarily spans the whole block. I think I will have to introduce some slop in this last Near Query in order to handle these cases. But if I choose to introduce slop greater than 0, then it will allow matches like this:

```
DELIMITER_TOKEN    
TOKEN_1            |                     |
TOKEN_2            | first near query    |        
TOKEN_8            |                     |
DELIMITER_TOKEN                          |   the top query
TOKEN_X                                  |
DELIMITER_TOKEN    | delitimer           |
TOKEN_3            | second near query   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it has turned out this is not a very good idea. I think it's a sign of a wrong search design if somebody wants to do things like this in Lucene.

However I found out the solution...(if anyone is interested)

The idea is that you have to store not only one delimiter tokens, but two of them. (Two different delimiters for each block: for example `DELIMITER1` and `DELIMITER2`)

Then you have to include the first delimiter in your SpanNearQuery (which would has a great slop), but you have to exclude the `DELIMITER2` from these results (with a SpanNotQuery).

Now you only have to construct a SpanNearQuery with slop 0, to "glue" the `DELIMITER1` to the previous query. And that's all. :)

But I think if somebody ever have to hack things like this, then it's time to revisit the actual search logic (I've finally concluded that maybe Lucene is not the best choice for this).